# How do I delete the brackets surrounding a certain word in python

Tags: python, regex

Hi I am trying to make a code that deletes the angle brackets whenever the word 'div' appears between the angle brackets.

```
<div class="ipc-page-content-container ipc-page-content-container--center" role="presentation"><a class="ipc-button ipc-button--double-padding ipc-button--default-height ipc-button--core-baseAlt ipc-button--theme-baseAlt ipc-button imdb-footer__open-in-app-button" href="/whitelist-offsite?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftqp-4.tlnk.io%2Fserve%3Faction%3Dclick%26campaign_id_android%3D427112%26campaign_id_ios%3D427111%26destination_id_android%3D464200%26destination_id_ios%3D464199%26my_campaign%3Dmdot%2520sitewide%2520footer%2520%26my_site%3Dm.imdb.com%26publisher_id%3D350552%26site_id_android%3D133429%26site_id_ios%3D133428&amp;page-action=ft-gettheapp&amp;ref=ft_apps" tabindex="0"><div class="ipc-button__text">Get the IMDb App</div></a></div></div><div class="ipc-page-content-container ipc-page-content-container--center _2AR8CsLqQAMCT1_Q7eidSY" role="presentation">
```

For example, the `<div class="ipc-page-content-container ipc-page-content-container--center" role="presentation">` would just become `div class="ipc-page-content-container ipc-page-content-container--center" role="presentation"` when using this code.

I tried to use regular expression to find div in the text, but I can't seem to find a way to delete the angle brackets.

```
import re
with open("movie.text.txt", 'rt', encoding='UTF8') as myfile:
    text = myfile.read()

    regex = "<div .+>"

    text = re.sub(regex, "div .+", text)
```

This code seems to delete every line of the text, and just replace it with `div .+`
Does anyone know how to make this code function properly?

Comment: I'd recommend using BeautifulSoup to parse html files instead of regex. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: I never thought of using BeautifulSoup, thanks for suggesting it!

Answer (score 0):

A simple **name_of_string. replace ('>' or'<', '')** should do the trick. The '' means nothing so they both get replaced with nothing. If this oneliner doesn't work, simply split the or statement and do one angle bracket at a time. **string_name.replace('>','')** then do same for the other angle bracket.

Comment: @Jeff is right though as this gives you more flexibility especially with cumbersome pages.

Comment: But this will replace all tags not only divs

Comment: Also try
<(div[^>]*)>
with group(1) to retrieve the match

Comment: Use if re.match('div') as condition and so if it's there perform the operation.

Comment: t = re.search(p,s)
if str(t) != "None":#OK
    print("$1:",t.group(1))#dd
can also be used to check the match result

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be like this:

```
regex = "<div .+>"

def matched(matchobj):
    return matchobj.group(0)[1:-1]

text = re.sub(regex, matched, text)
```

This gives a callback function to `re.sub()` which is called for every match and returns a replacement string. In this replacement string we just slice the first and last char of the string.

`matchobj.group(0)` will return the whole matched string